# Pusher on Python run forever

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, pusher

I am learning to use websockets for a new project.  I want to monitor live streams of messages coming through multiple different socket connections.  It just so happens one of the socket APIs uses [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).  I like to work in python, so I found [the pusherclient pacakge on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pusherclient/0.3.0).  For the other connections I am using [the websocket-client package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client).

So The question I have, is there a better way to have the pusher client run forever besides the `while True:` loop that they have in the example:

```
...
global pusher

# We can't subscribe until we've connected, so we use a callback handler
# to subscribe when able
def connect_handler(data):
    channel = pusher.subscribe('mychannel')
    channel.bind('myevent', callback)

pusher = pusherclient.Pusher(appkey)
pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
pusher.connect()

while True:
    # Do other things in the meantime here...
    time.sleep(1)
```

This works but seems to really suck the CPU.  Using the `websocket-client` package, there is an example on the pypi page which shows how to run the client forever:

```
...
#omitted function definitions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

I tested both types of code, and they both work, but the websocket-client seems to use a lot less CPU than the pusherclient.  Since I need multiple clients to be open at the same time, I really want to save resources.  I was thinking there should a better, prettier, and hopefully less expensive way of getting the socket to stay alive than the `while True` loop.  Does anyone know a good technique?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is, and what happens instead. Is the socket getting closed? It's also not clear what library you're using - it sounds like you're using two different libraries to connect to Pusher as a client.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I guess it wasn't very clear.  I am using 2 libraries to connection to 2 ( or more ) websocket feed simultaneously.  I guess it isn't a great question, I think I'll close it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `Pusher` client is a deamon which means that the underlying thread runs in the background and it won't keep the main python thread from closing.

At least in the newer versions (Ex: 0.6.0b2) there is an initialization argument called `daemon` which you can set to `False` so that you don't need to leave in the `while` loop.

Example:

```
pusher = pusherclient.Pusher(appkey, daemon=False)
pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
pusher.connect()

# No need for a while True as the underlying non-daemon thread will prevent the process 
# from dying automatically.
```